# How to make a random list with a sum of 1 with minimum and maximum limits for each element?

Tags: python, list, portfolio

I'm currently working on a long-short portfolio optimization project with python.

The thing is that I have to generate a list that has a sum of 1 and each element of the list should be larger or equal to -1 and smaller and equal to 5.

The length of the list must be 5 and the elements should be floats.

Is there a way that I could make such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the constraint that the weights must sum to `1`, there are only really **four** sources of randomness here.  So, generate potential weights for the first four assets:

```
weights = [random.uniform(-1, 5) for i in range(4)]
```

then infer if the final weight `final_weight = 1 - sum(weights)` meets requirements.  So something like:

```
def generate_weights():
    while True:
        weights = [random.uniform(-1, 5) for i in range(4)]
        weights.append(1 - sum(weights))
        if -1 <= weights[-1] <= 5:
            return weights
```

Comment: Interesting. All five numbers seem to end up with [the same non-uniform distribution](https://tio.run/##ZZDLasQwDEX3/gpBF2MPk1c7gVI6q/5CdyEMIVESQ/zAdgj9@tR2Mg1MtbKupasj6R83Kvn2rs26cqGVcWAa2SlBeqMEtGqasHVcSQv795eapUNDSIc9DCjRNA7vC/JhdJayDwI@lpFPCN9mxi2P2lYCN6i2Eeksea@MoElxgZKBfwMHLgPBgPTK6ufetNEaZUcLSMDOgu4yY3@FvIekgM/bo6NKijqk5cERwqCbjXwUEbLYyPV/nQh1P6CK/HwOYE@s5b5364z32U9EF1vxGrIM8rSEDF6j2WJDmx@4QUfpAn0Qrb8vdtSbpNyh8OPZga0Nl47GUu9Y5nCG08uJresv). I would've thought the last one's distribution would differ.